# Motor shield not moving as expected

Tags: arduino, motordriver

Motor shield is not working as expected when connected to battery. When Arduino is connected to USB, motor is moving both FORWARD and BACKWARD, but when connected to battery, it moving only in FORWARD direction. I don't think so it's battery issue, because motor speed is good even it moves only in FORWARD direction.

Below is the code,

```
#include <AFMotor.h>

AF_DCMotor motor1(1);
AF_DCMotor motor2(2);


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Motor");
  motor1.setSpeed(254);
  motor2.setSpeed(254);
  motor1.run(RELEASE);
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
 }

 void loop() {
 motor1.run(BACKWARD);
 motor2.run(BACKWARD);
 delay(500);

 motor1.run(FORWARD);
 motor2.run(FORWARD);
 delay(500);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires a little power trigger or if we wait for around 2-3 minutes the motor works good. Motor shield drains the battery often. Seems to be it requires more power supply. Power supply from USB cable works perfectly rather than batteries

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should work with your above code. But note that there is a jumper on the shield that you have to remove in order to power it through the battery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please elaborate

Comment: On your motor shield there will be a jumper just below the middle IC with PWR written. Remove it and then try again.

Comment: Tried removing, motor itself is not working in this case